# jQuery UI Dialog Box - link with javascript function

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-dialog

Is it possible to have a link in the jquery dialog box which calls a javascript function? something like this -

```
var msg-dialog = $('#dialog-msg');
msg-dialog .html("Please click < a href='javascript:void(0)' onclick='javascript:reload();'>here</a> to reload.");
msg-dialog('open');

 function reload() {
      // do something.
      alert('test');
    }
```

The link shows up in the dialog just fine but clicking it doesn't do anything. What am I missing? I also want to close the dialog in the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have the appropriate libraries, this will work right out of the box:

```
<html>
<head>
<link href="jqueryUI/css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.8.19.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script src="jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
<script src="jqueryUI/js/jquery-ui-1.8.19.custom.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
function doSomething() {
    $('#dialog').dialog('close');
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#dialog").dialog();
    $("#dialog").html("<a href=\"#\" onclick=\"doSomething();\">Call doSomething() function!</a>");
});
</script>

</head>
<body>
<div id="dialog"></div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This is working, but when you set the inner text (the hyperlink) on the fly, it doesn't.

Comment: Where do you want to set the inner text?

Comment: In the `ready` function for example - `$(document).ready(function() {
    $( "#dialog" ).html('<a href='#' onclick='doSomething();'>Call doSomething() function!</a>');` I found out that it's unable to find the function.

Comment: I made a small edit to reflect what you're trying to do. The changes made seem to be working.

Comment: That worked! I had to remove the javascript tag and also escape the whole thing! Thank you very much.

Comment: Happy to help. An "accepted answer" from you would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

`msg-dialog` is an invalid variable according to ECMAScript 5.1 / Unicode 6.1.

```
var msg_dialog = $('#dialog-msg');
msg_dialog .html("Please click <a href='javascript:void(0)' onclick='javascript:reload();'>here</a> to reload.");
msg_dialog.dialog(); // notice this
```

and `< a href='...'>here</a>` has a space before **a** that should be`<a href='...'>here</a>`

[**DEMO.**](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/RL23U/2/)

[**Javascript variable name validator.**](http://mothereff.in/js-variables#%E0%B2%A0_%E0%B2%A0)

Comment: I understand what you're saying. Regarding the space before the a, I've added the space deliberately as the SO software can display the text. WIthout the space, it's actually parsing it.

Comment: The demo works perfectly. I just looked in the Console window of Firebug and it says 'reload is not defined'. I think it is looking for the function in a different location. But the function is right there and it named correctly. If I add the alert inline like `< a href.. onclick'javascript:alert('test');`, it works correctly.

Comment: Keep the `function reload(){...}` inside `head` tag.

Comment: I actually have one .js file for my application. It is referenced in the master page of the application. Do you want me to move the function in  my .js file to the master page's head tag?

Comment: You can keep the function inside you js file if it's referenced and but it should be included in the master page properly.

Comment: It is referenced correctly. All other functions work without a problem. It's just this one function that is causing issues. Any ideas?

Comment: Not sure but you can move the whole script tag from demo inside the head tag of your master page.

Comment: That will take a while as I have a lot of stuff going on the .js file. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!